# Ubuntu 18.04 hanging completely after or at startup

Tags: boot, hardware, cpu

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 hanging (even 'reisub' not responding) sometimes during the boot and sometimes when I start to run some programs.

I suspect a hardware issue but I don't know if this `mce` entries are normal.

```
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 2
CPU 0 THERMAL EVENT TSC 1a4e0503fb8 
TIME 1556879463 Fri May  3 11:31:03 2019
Processor 0 below trip temperature. Throttling disabled
Running trigger `unknown-error-trigger'
mcelog: Too many trigger children running already
STATUS 2 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP 180204 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 15 Model 4
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 3
CPU 1 THERMAL EVENT TSC 1a4e0507ff0 
TIME 1556879463 Fri May  3 11:31:03 2019
Processor 1 below trip temperature. Throttling disabled
Running trigger `unknown-error-trigger'
mcelog: Too many trigger children running already
STATUS 2 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP 180204 APICID 1 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 15 Model 4
Kernel does not support page offline interface
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 0 BANK 0 
TIME 1181693956 Wed Jun 13 01:19:16 2007
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
Processor context corrupt
MCA: BUS error: 0 0 Level-3 Local-CPU-originated-request Generic Other-transaction Request-did-not-timeout
Running trigger `bus-error-trigger'
Model:Pad address glitch

STATUS a20000001080080f MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP 180204 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 15 Model 4
Kernel does not support page offline interface
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 0 BANK 0 
TIME 1557687406 Sun May 12 19:56:46 2019
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
Processor context corrupt
MCA: Internal Timer error
Running trigger `unknown-error-trigger'
STATUS a200000088010400 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP 180204 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 15 Model 4
```

I cleaned fans and even replaced processor's thermal paste but I still have the same problem and I'm not sure if the issue really comes from the hardware since I got this errors during the boot.

```
journzlctl -b | grep error
mai 13 20:53:44 kh-PVM890M kernel: EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
mai 13 20:54:00 kh-PVM890M kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: L-EC uncorrectable error
mai 13 20:54:00 kh-PVM890M kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 748816 flags 80700
mai 13 20:54:04 kh-PVM890M kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: L-EC uncorrectable error
mai 13 20:54:04 kh-PVM890M kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 748816 flags 0
mai 13 20:54:04 kh-PVM890M kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 187204, async page read
mai 13 20:54:04 kh-PVM890M kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 187205, async page read
```

The system doesn't hang if I start in rescue mode even if I run the `stress` utility with any load (CPU, Memory, I/O) but will hang shortly after I `startx` or `startxfce4`. That's the weird thing.

How can I determine the root cause and possibly fix it ? Thanks in advance

[edit] for @heynnema
 # df -h

```
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev               701M       0  701M   0% /dev
tmpfs              144M    1,1M  143M   1% /run
/dev/sda7           22G     15G  5,9G  72% /
tmpfs              718M       0  718M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs              718M       0  718M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

# grep -i temp /var/log/syslog*

```
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:46 kh-PVM890M smartd[717]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 230 to 240
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:49 kh-PVM890M sensors[770]: temp1:        +25.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:49 kh-PVM890M sensors[770]: temp2:        +37.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermal diode
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:49 kh-PVM890M sensors[770]: temp3:       -128.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = disabled
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:09 kh-PVM890M systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:09 kh-PVM890M systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:45 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   98.787028] kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt? (uid: 0)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 13:40:56 kh-PVM890M systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 13:40:57 kh-PVM890M smartd[711]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 240 to 214
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 13:41:01 kh-PVM890M sensors[765]: temp1:        +25.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 13:41:01 kh-PVM890M sensors[765]: temp2:        +42.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermal diode
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 13:41:01 kh-PVM890M sensors[765]: temp3:       -128.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = disabled
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 13:41:22 kh-PVM890M systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 13:41:22 kh-PVM890M systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
```

# grep -i mem /var/log/syslog*

```
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e7000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000005ff9ffff] usable
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005ffa0000-0x000000005ffadfff] ACPI data
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005ffae000-0x000000005ffeffff] ACPI NVS
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005fff0000-0x000000005fffffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fecc0000-0x00000000fecc0fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff780000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.013355] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.013359] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.029251] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000ff780-0x000ff78f]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.061933] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.061935] initial memory mapped: [mem 0x00000000-0x053fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.061944] Base memory trampoline at [(ptrval)] 9b000 size 16384
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.062088] RAMDISK: [mem 0x33d01000-0x35e77fff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.062359] 649MB HIGHMEM available.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.062362] 885MB LOWMEM available.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069122]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069126]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000375fdfff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069128]   HighMem  [mem 0x00000000375fe000-0x000000005ff9ffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069131] Early memory node ranges
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069133]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069135]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000005ff9ffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069147] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000005ff9ffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069153]   DMA zone: 40 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.069373]   Normal zone: 2175 pages used for memmap
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.081354]   HighMem zone: 166306 pages, LIFO batch:31
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.090717] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.090721] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.090722] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000e6fff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.090724] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e7000-0x000fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.090729] [mem 0x60000000-0xfebfffff] available for PCI devices
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.186257] Initializing HighMem for node 0 (000375fe:0005ffa0)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.282066] Memory: 1434860K/1572088K available (9390K kernel code, 903K rwdata, 3604K rodata, 1112K init, 868K bss, 137228K reserved, 0K cma-reserved, 665224K highmem)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.282077] virtual kernel memory layout:
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.282077]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xf75fe000   ( 885 MB)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.347042] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 36K
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.367460] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x5ffae000-0x5ffeffff] (270336 bytes)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.370493] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.383388] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.386348] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] reserved in ACPI motherboard resources
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.404422] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.404425] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d0000-0x000dffff window]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.404427] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x60000000-0xff77ffff window]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.404490] pci 0000:00:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.407166] pci 0000:00:08.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xff6f0000-0xff6fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.409172] pci 0000:00:10.4: reg 0x10: [mem 0xff6efc00-0xff6efcff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.410329] pci 0000:00:12.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xff6ef800-0xff6ef8ff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.410827] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd0000000-0xd7ffffff pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.410850] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xff5f0000-0xff5fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.410888] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xff5c0000-0xff5dffff pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.411108] pci 0000:02:00.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xff5e0000-0xff5effff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.411327] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xff500000-0xff5fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.411335] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xcff00000-0xdfefffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.415535] pci 0000:02:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.415535] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x0009fc00-0x0009ffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.415535] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x5ffa0000-0x5fffffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.456049] system 00:06: [mem 0xff380000-0xff3fffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.456204] system 00:07: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff] could not be reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.456207] system 00:07: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.457631] system 00:09: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.457974] system 00:0a: [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff] could not be reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.457978] system 00:0a: [mem 0x000c0000-0x000cffff] could not be reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.457981] system 00:0a: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff] could not be reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.457984] system 00:0a: [mem 0x00100000-0x5fffffff] could not be reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.457987] system 00:0a: [mem 0xff780000-0xffffffff] has been reserved
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496800] pci 0000:00:03.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 03] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496803] pci 0000:00:03.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 03] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496820] pci 0000:00:03.0: BAR 14: assigned [mem 0x60000000-0x601fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496830] pci 0000:00:03.0: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x60200000-0x603fffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496866] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xff500000-0xff5fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496871] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xcff00000-0xdfefffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496888] pci 0000:00:03.0:   bridge window [mem 0x60000000-0x601fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496894] pci 0000:00:03.0:   bridge window [mem 0x60200000-0x603fffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496909] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496911] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000dffff window]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496914] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x60000000-0xff77ffff window]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496919] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xff500000-0xff5fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496922] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xcff00000-0xdfefffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496927] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0x60000000-0x601fffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.496929] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0x60200000-0x603fffff 64bit pref]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    0.499262] pci 0000:02:00.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    1.474633] Freeing initrd memory: 34268K
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    1.474693] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x2fd01000-0x33d01000] (64MB)
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    1.475007] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    2.021893] ehci-pci 0000:00:10.4: irq 21, io mem 0xff6efc00
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [    2.104213] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1112K
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   23.015236] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000dffff window]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   23.017298] [drm] Generation 2 PCI interface, using max accessible memory
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   23.025215] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 402526 kiB
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   23.025220] [TTM] Zone highmem: Available graphics memory: 735138 kiB
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   23.025294] [drm] radeon: 128M of VRAM memory ready
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:30:43 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   23.025297] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:29 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=1731 comm="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="kernel")
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:29 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:30 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=1731 comm="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="kernel")
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:30 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:30 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=1731 comm="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="kernel")
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:30 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:30 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=1731 comm="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="kernel")
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:31 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:31 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=1731 comm="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tumbler-1/tumblerd " label="kernel")
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:31 kh-PVM890M dbus-daemon[1442]: [session uid=1000 pid=1442] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:45 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   98.787494] Modules linked in: msr ccm uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common snd_usb_audio videodev media snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hwdep snd_via82xx snd_mpu401_uart intel_powerclamp gameport snd_via82xx_modem snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi radeon snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi input_leds ttm snd_seq serio_raw drm_kms_helper arc4 drm i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd sysfillrect soundcore sysimgblt ath5k ath mac80211 cfg80211 mac_hid binfmt_misc sch_fq_codel it87 hwmon_vid parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 pata_acpi hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse via_rhine mii i2c_viapro sata_via pata_via floppy
/var/log/syslog.1:May 11 12:31:46 kh-PVM890M kernel: [   99.302227] Modules linked in: msr ccm uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common snd_usb_audio videodev media snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hwdep snd_via82xx snd_mpu401_uart intel_powerclamp gameport snd_via82xx_modem snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi radeon snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi input_leds ttm snd_seq serio_raw drm_kms_helper arc4 drm i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device snd_timer fb_sys_fops syscopyarea snd sysfillrect soundcore sysimgblt ath5k ath mac80211 cfg80211 mac_hid binfmt_misc sch_fq_codel it87 hwmon_vid parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 pata_acpi hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse via_rhine mii i2c_viapro sata_via pata_via floppy
```

Output from memtest

```
memtester version 4.3.0 (32-bit)
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Charles Cazabon.
Licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2 (only).

pagesize is 4096
pagesizemask is 0xfffff000
want 1024MB (1073741824 bytes)
got  1024MB (1073741824 bytes), trying mlock ...locked.
Loop 1/5:
  Stuck Address       : ok
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok
  Block Sequential    : ok
  Checkerboard        : ok
  Bit Spread          : ok
  Bit Flip            : ok
  Walking Ones        : ok
  Walking Zeroes      : ok
  8-bit Writes        : ok
  16-bit Writes       : ok

Loop 2/5:
  Stuck Address       : ok
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok
  Block Sequential    : ok
  Checkerboard        : ok
  Bit Spread          : ok
  Bit Flip            : ok
  Walking Ones        : ok
  Walking Zeroes      : ok
  8-bit Writes        : ok
  16-bit Writes       : ok

Loop 3/5:
  Stuck Address       : ok
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok
  Block Sequential    : ok
  Checkerboard        : ok
  Bit Spread          : ok
  Bit Flip            : ok
  Walking Ones        : ok
  Walking Zeroes      : ok
  8-bit Writes        : ok
  16-bit Writes       : ok

Loop 4/5:
  Stuck Address       : ok
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok
  Block Sequential    : ok
  Checkerboard        : ok
  Bit Spread          : ok
  Bit Flip            : ok
  Walking Ones        : ok
  Walking Zeroes      : ok
  8-bit Writes        : ok
  16-bit Writes       : ok

Loop 5/5:
  Stuck Address       : ok
  Random Value        : ok
  Compare XOR         : ok
  Compare SUB         : ok
  Compare MUL         : ok
  Compare DIV         : ok
  Compare OR          : ok
  Compare AND         : ok
  Sequential Increment: ok
  Solid Bits          : ok
  Block Sequential    : ok
  Checkerboard        : ok
  Bit Spread          : ok
  Bit Flip            : ok
  Walking Ones        : ok
  Walking Zeroes      : ok
  8-bit Writes        : ok
  16-bit Writes       : ok

Done.
```

Comment: sr0 is probably your DVD drive... do you have a disc inserted? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i temp /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i mem /var/log/syslog*`. Do you know how to run `memtest`?

Comment: yes @heynnema sr0 is my DVD drive. The disk I used to try a live system for troubleshooting is still there. I edited the question. I will also try to run a memtest.

Comment: Do you have a software RAM disk installed?

Comment: No I don't (since I'm not sure about what it is I don't think I have one). The memtest isn't showing up in the grub so I run it via `memtester 1024 5`

Comment: Download the free memtest from memtest86.com, drop it onto a flash drive, and you can run from there. We should also check your BIOS. `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, then go to the manufacturor's web site and check for updates.

Comment: Unfortunately memtest86 creates an USB bootable image that I can't use with my quite old machine that can't boot from USB. The `memtester` output isn't enough ? The `dmidecode` returned `080013` and it's an American Megatrends. I looked their websites and it seems I need to install windows to be able to run their upgrate tool. Am I right ?

Comment: ah yes... the older machines are getting harder to support. Memtester is fine. And yes, you probably do need Windows to install BIOS updates, but you should read the install docs, as some can do it right from the old BIOS. You could also try to build a flash drive with "FreeDOS" or something like it... if your machine can even boot from USB...

Comment: I got this when trying to Install FreeDOS [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/73Bipvk)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your screenshot indicates either a hardware problem, or you grabbed the wrong version of FreeDOS. I guess that you'll just have to find a way to boot a 32-bit version of Windows to do the BIOS update.

Comment: I think I have the same issue on some on my Ubuntu boots. A similar screen just goes on until the timer on the left reaches 120 and then it reboots. Therefore, I'd go for the hardware problem. Any tool to diagnose this ?

Comment: What else does it say on the line with the 120 second timer? It should tell you what service is having trouble starting up.

Comment: It just scrolls too fast. Completely unreadable. I'll try to reproduce the problem and take a picture. But it is a long line with some Hexadecimal code that's reproduced.

Comment: Just create a small movie file of the startup screen during the problem. Keep a steady hand though.

Comment: When you try to reproduce a problem and then you get [a new one](https://imgur.com/a/Jv791Fq). Note the blurred line was actually displayed by the boot sequence. It's not a screen issue.

Comment: I also have `Puppy Linux` as a dual boot. [That's not better](https://imgur.com/a/ck8FM62)

Comment: Is this a desktop or laptop machine? One video card, or two?

Comment: It's a desktop machine.I think one `ATI` video card.

Comment: Does it have any PCI or PCIe cards? Internal video also? Did you ever update the BIOS as we had discussed before?

Comment: Since I couldn't boot on `FreeDOS` I still couldn't update my bios. My [`lspci`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kHZbmhh45J/).